# Заставить сервер отправлять данные остальным клиентам?

Tags: java, сервер, сеть, сокет, клиент-сервер

Нужна помощь, я делаю некий многопользовательский чат

Когда я подключаюсь несколькими клинетами к одному серверу, то сообщения должны отправлятся всем подключённым сразу, а не только отправителю

Метод и поля класса сервера:

```
private JPanel contentPane;
static JLabel status;
private ServerSocket ss;
private boolean server_enabled = false;
public static final String waiting = "Waiting for connection...";
public static final String connection_recieved = "Recieved connection!";
private static int Port;

public void runServer() {
    if(server_enabled == true) {
        Thread sockedThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ss = new ServerSocket(Port);
                    System.out.println(waiting);
                    status.setText(waiting);
                    System.out.println("Socket created!");

                    while(true) {
                    Socket socket = ss.accept();
                        System.out.println(connection_recieved);
                        new ServerThread(socket).start();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
        });
        sockedThread.start();
    }
    else {
        try {
            ss.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {return;}
        return;
    }
}
```

ServerThread:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerThread extends Thread{

Socket client_socket;

public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
    this.client_socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(ServerFrame.connection_recieved);
        ServerFrame.status.setText(ServerFrame.connection_recieved);

        InputStream sis = client_socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream sos = client_socket.getOutputStream();

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sis);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sos);

        while (true) {
            String InputLine = DataInputStream.readUTF(in);
            if(InputLine.contains("Username:")) {
                String[] x = InputLine.split("Username:");
                ServerFrame.dlm.addElement(x[1]);
            }else {
            System.out.println(InputLine);
            ServerFrame.ChatArea.append((InputLine));
            out.writeUTF(InputLine);
            out.flush();
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException ioException) {}
    }

}
```

Метод и поля клиента(ов):

```
private JTextField InputField;
private JTextField Port;
private JTextField Ip;
private String IpAdress;
private int ServerPort;
private InetAddress ServerIp;
private JButton Send;
private String textToSend;
private JTextField Username;
private JTextArea ChatArea;


public void startConntection() {
try {
    Thread connectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream sis;
                OutputStream sos;
                Socket socket;
                DataInputStream in;
                DataOutputStream out;

                IpAdress = Ip.getText().trim();
                ServerPort = Integer.valueOf(Port.getText().trim());
                try {
                    ServerIp = InetAddress.getByName(IpAdress);
                }catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
                    ChatArea.append("Unable to connect! Invalid ip!"+"\n");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(ServerIp) + "lolo" + ServerPort);
                socket = new Socket(ServerIp, ServerPort);
                ChatArea.append("Establishing connection..."+"\n");
                sis = socket.getInputStream();
                sos = socket.getOutputStream();

                in = new DataInputStream(sis);
                out = new DataOutputStream(sos);
                ChatArea.append("Streams created..."+"\n");

                String usernameRequest = "Username:" + Username.getText();
                out.writeUTF(usernameRequest+"\n");

                ChatArea.append("Connection succesful!"+"\n");

                Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        textToSend = Username.getText() + ">> " + InputField.getText() + "\n".replace("Username:", "");
                        try {
                            System.out.println("This:"+textToSend);
                            out.writeUTF(textToSend);
                            out.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {}
                    }
                });

                while(true) {
                    String textToAdd = in.readUTF();
                    ChatArea.append(textToAdd);
                }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            ChatArea.append("Unable to connect! No server found!"+"\n");
        }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            ChatArea.append("Unable to connect! Invalid ip!"+"\n");}
        }
    });
    connectionThread.start();
}catch (Exception e) {return;}
}
```

Я скопировал только нужный код, остальное это кнопки и фрейм.

Первый раз спрашиваю здесь, но думаю всё оформил правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно хранить список *Socket*-ов или *OutputStream*-ов. Я покажу на примере *OutputStream*-ов (метод отправки сообщений, в этом случае, будет проще).

Итак, имеем поле:

```
private List<PrintWriter> clientWriters = new ArrayList<>();
```

При подключении нового пользователя нужно поместить его *PrintWriter* в список:

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);
clientWriters.add(writer);
```

Метод для отправки сообщений всем пользователям (в том числе отправителю) будет следующим:

```
private void tellEveryone(String message) {
    try {
        for(PrintWriter writer : clientWriters) {
            writer.println(message);
            System.out.println("Message " + message + " sent to users");
            writer.flush();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

**P. S.** Как видите метод объявлен с модификатором `private`. Я считаю, что вне класса (сервера) его вызывать нету смысла.